# add class to @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I add a class to this @Html.ActionLink?  I've tried many suggestion and none have worked so far.

```
                        @Html.ActionLink("Physician Profile",
                                     "Print",
                                     "Roster",
                                     new { profilePrintType = ProfilePrintType.PhysicianProfile},
                                     new { style="padding:2px 10px;" })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for reserved words you have to add @

```
new { @style="padding:2px 10px;", @class = "className" })
```

Comment: thanks I was trying to add a new line like new {  @class = "className" } and getting errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Physician Profile",
  "Print",
  "Roster",
  new { profilePrintType = ProfilePrintType.PhysicianProfile},
  new { style="padding:2px 10px;", @class = "some-css-class" })
```